# jquery get display property with .next()

Tags: jquery, css

I want to get css display property value of a div.
I am using this codes

```
function addcommentdiv() {
    $('.comment-body').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), $reply = $this.next('cevapla');
        var cevapladisplay = $reply.css('display');
        alert(cevapladisplay);
    });
};
```

But this codes return "undefined". How can I get display property of $reply object ?

CSS codes

```
<li class="comment">

  <div class="comment-body" id="comment-body">
    <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <div class="lightbox-photo">
        <a class="image-overlay" href='<%# "Foto/profil/foto_buyuk/" + Eval("Yorum_Profil_Foto_Buyuk") %>' data-rel="prettyPhoto" title='<%# Eval("Yorum_UserName")%>'><img src='<%# "Foto/profil/foto_kucuk/" + Eval("Yorum_Profil_Foto_Kucuk") %>' alt='<%# Eval("Yorum_UserName")%>' class="avatar" /></a>
      </div>
      <cite class="fn"><asp:HyperLink ID="linkProfil" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Yorum_UserName")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# "~/profil.aspx?user_id="+Eval("User_ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink></cite>
      <cite class="fn-time"></cite> 
    </div>
    <p><%# Eval("Yorum_Text")%></p>
  </div>

  <!-- MORE CODE HERE -->      

  <div class="cevapla" id="cevapla" >
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtCevapla" runat="server"    CssClass="cevaplatextbox" ></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btnCevapla" runat="server" Text="Button" />
  </div>

</li>
```

Comment: My guess is `$this.next('cevapla');` isn't selecting any elements. Debug from top to bottom, not the opposite.

Comment: Let's see your HTML, OP. You are getting `undefined` because the selector isn't accurate.

Comment: You have an extra closing `</div>` tag right before `.cevapla` and you can just use plain old `.next()` in this case.

Comment: @KevinB I updated my post :)  $this.next('cevapla'); is selecting element.

Comment: As the answers below point out, `$this.next('cevapla');` doesn't make any sense, since `cevapla` isn't a tag.  You need to use `$this.next('#cevapla');` or `$this.next('.cevapla');`

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte I deleted some unnecessary code Maybe I missed :)

Comment: @Steve I tried all of them.When I wrote alert($reply.lenght) its working but I want to get display property.

Comment: @serdar That doesn't make any sense. It should not select any elements because you don't have any `<cevapla></cevapla>` elements.

Comment: @serdar You shouldn't be using duplicate ID's in this case, either. If you have a bunch of list items with the same ID, you need to re-think the markup.

Comment: Thanks friends.I solved with 
Rick Viscomi's answer :) I missed something.Thanks

Comment: pfff sorry I didnt solve....That codes just work on one div.I have a list pffffff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed ".next" to ".find".It is working (A bit slow than .next)

```
function addcommentdiv() {
$('.comment-body').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), $reply = $this.find('.cevapla');
    var cevapladisplay = $reply.css('display');
    alert(cevapladisplay);
});
```

}

addcommentdiv();

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `next` method accepts a selector as the parameter. http://api.jquery.com/next/

As a follow up to the original post, here is the fixed code:

```
function addcommentdiv() {
    $('.comment-body').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), $reply = $this.next('.cevapla');
        var cevapladisplay = $reply.css('display');
        alert(cevapladisplay);
    });
}
```

I removed the `;` on the last curly brace because this is a function declaration.

In a comment the asker also mentioned that `cevapla` is the ID of the element as well. In this case, it would make more sense to rewrite the assignment to `$reply = $('#cevapla')` assuming the ID is unique.

Comment: owww so sorry :/ Its working.You are right mate.So sorry and much thanks

Comment: It doesnt solve.I have a list of divs.So I was using .next for this.Now its working for just one div.......

Comment: IDs in HTML are supposed to be unique for each element. If it is not unique, use a class instead. I will update my answer.

Comment: yeah but I have commentlist.I cant give unique id for all list item.As I said I was using .next() for this :/

Comment: You should not use `id="cevapla"` in the first place if it will be repeated for every comment. I've already updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I cant give different id for all div.Its list.Maybe I can give different id but then I cant select id

Comment: So I have to use .next() to get.

Comment: @serdar I have no idea why it wouldn't be working for you. Given the small amount of HTML and JavaScript you provided, it is working in this test: http://jsfiddle.net/RnNx8/ My answer **is** using `.next()`.

Comment: I cant believe..As you said it is working in test..But still isn't working on my page :S

Comment: I cant find any reason pffffffffffff

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a selector:

```
var $this = $(this), $reply = $this.next('.cevapla');
```

I don't know what cevapla is, is it a class? You can find out if jQuery has selected an element by doing:

```
console.log($this.next(".cevapla").length);
```

Comment: div class="cevapla" id="cevapla" ></div> cevapla is div id,and css class

Comment: Than I'd preffer you using the id selector, since it is faster.

Comment: @serdar You're making everyone guess. Just put your HTML in the question so we can give you the right answer. :)